# How to search and replace with a capture group in VBA

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I want to use a regular expression in VBA to do a search, capture part of it, and then use that part in the replacement. For example, I want to run the search and replace on these lines:

```
(a4a)
(aHa)
```

And get a result of:

```
(b4b)
(bHb)
```

How do I capture the 2nd character and use it again in the replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBA, capture parts of the search with parenthesis `()` and use them in replacement with `$` and the number of the capture occurrence. Note, normal parenthesis need to be escaped, which is the opposite of vim.

So in this case:

```
searchPattern = "\(a(.)a\)"
replacement = "(b$1b)"
```